# Can SimpleXML load only a partial of a XML?

Tags: php, xml

Is there a way not to load the whole feed but only the first 10 `<item></item>` tag?

```
$feed = 'rss file';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed); //not the entire feed though
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A DOM parser (such as SimpleXML) can only load the entire document.

But you can use XPath to filter the relevant parts:

```
$xml   = simplexml_load_file($feed);
$top10 = $xml->xpath('/rss/channel/item[position() <= 10]');

foreach($top10 as $item) {
   // output $item;
}
```

Comment: I tried to add it the position in mine xPath but I don't get it right. This is it: `array_merge($entries, $xml->xpath('/f:feed/f:entry | /rss/channel//item'));`

Comment: for those namespaced items (`f:*`) see [`registerXPathNamespace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php)

Comment: I have set the namespaces as `$xml->registerXPathNamespace('f', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');` all works correctly (I echo the content,title...) But how do I modify my xPath to include the `position`?

Comment: Well, just add `[position() <= 10]`? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Thanks I did that. One more question though. Even by this the entire document is loades but I reduce the size of the array?

Comment: Yes, the array will be little smaller.

Comment: Thank you I have accepted your answer. I guess smaller array means faster performance, right?

Answer (score 2):

With use of the [XMLReader](http://php.net/book.xmlreader) you can achieve this. This avoids the consumption of large amount of RAM.

```
$xmlr = new XMLReader();
$xmlr->open('path/to/file');
// ...
// move the pointer with $xmlr->read(), $xmlr->next(), etc. to the required
// elements and read them with simplexml_load_string($xmlr->readOuterXML()), etc.
// ...
$xmlr->close();
```

Comment: I have tried XMLReader in a previous application but the difference in speed is huge against simpleXML.