# PHP - Get only certain data from XML, not whole xml file?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I need to get online users data from xml file, but simplexml_load_file seems slow. File is big because online users are a lot. I am trying to paginate them 20 per page I have...

```
<?php $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://domain.tld/data.xml'); ?>
```

Then

```
<?php echo $xml->who_is_online[1]->thumbnail_image; ?>
<?php echo $xml->who_is_online[1]->display_name; ?>
<?php echo $xml->who_is_online[1]->display_age; ?>
```

But there should be about 20 of these per page.

```
<?php echo $xml->who_is_online[2]->thumbnail_image; ?>
<?php echo $xml->who_is_online[2]->display_name; ?>
<?php echo $xml->who_is_online[2]->display_age; ?>
<?php echo $xml->who_is_online[3]->thumbnail_image; ?>
<?php echo $xml->who_is_online[3]->display_name; ?>
<?php echo $xml->who_is_online[3]->display_age; ?>
```

etc. (to 20)

What is the better way to get only this certain data from XML without reading the whole file on each page load? I mean get data for user 1 to user 20 on 1st page, then on 2nd page get data for user 21 to 40, etc. On 2nd page I have the same code but getting data for [21], [22], [23], etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleXML can't partially read a document. Even with an XPath filter, the whole document is still parsed behind the scenes.

A possible solution is use a cronjob or scheduled task to regularly call a PHP script which downloads the XML, parses it and inserts the data into an SQL database (don't forget to delete the old data first).

When a visitor requests a page, just paginate the data using SQL queries on the database.

Comment: Same data is offered to me via json or yaml. Is there a way to partly process json or yaml?

Comment: Practically no because in order to pull out certain data from the file, the whole file must first be read and parsed. The only real option is to cache the data somewhere (as in the answer) or to ask the data provider to allow you to pass a page number to filter by.

Answer (score 1):

> A DOM parser (such as SimpleXML) can only load the entire document.

See: [Can SimpleXML load only a partial of a XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628999/can-simplexml-load-only-a-partial-of-a-xml)

but you can iteratethrough your 'who_is_online'.

```
for ($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
    echo $xml->who_is_online[$i]->thumbnail_image;
    echo $xml->who_is_online[$i]->display_name;
    echo $xml->who_is_online[$i]->display_age;
}
```

Comment: How to achieve this, if I did not use the actual number but defined $current on each page and then [($current + 1)], [($current + 2)], etc. for each user?

Comment: if $current is your actual page then [$current+$i] should work.

Comment: I will try this, too. $current is the current starting user. I have another variable to define page.