# load only part of an xml file with php

Tags: php, xml

I know I can use simplexml_load_file to load an xml file. The problem is, the xml file is HUGE, so it takes a while to load. The XML file is long, but is broken down into categories. I'm wondering if I can load just a portion of the file, based on the category. What I'd like to do is search the file before loading it completely, find the category that applies, and load only the nodes from that category. Somehow I don't think this can be done using just PHP... but I thought I'd ask.

Here is the feed,
http://www.sandiego.org/san-diego/xml-feeds/what-to-do-feed.aspx
 and I'm trying to only pull an `<item>` node of its `<category>` is Fishing

Comment: you can choose to only load specific nodes. Find the category you need, then use xpath to grab it

Comment: This is great, and I did not know about this, but I'm not sure it will work for my purposes.. because I need to load an entire section based on a category ID. For example, this file 
http://www.sandiego.org/san-diego/xml-feeds/what-to-do-feed.aspx
I want to load the everything in the <item> node, but ONLY if <attribute16><category> is Fishing
I can probably script this, but won't the script run slow and then defeat the purpose of only trying to load specific nodes?

Comment: edit your post and add a portion of the xml file (not all of it, just a large enough segment to see a few categories), and it will make it easier to answer.

Comment: I can also break this feed up into several smaller feeds, would that be better?

Comment: I meant copy some of the code, not the link, which may change.

Comment: do you mean that you want to pull everything from a parent node (e.g. "attribute16") that has a node with the value of "fishing" within it? such as "Tours & Sightseeing" and "Boating"?   or do you just want to load "attribute16"?

Comment: yes I want to pull everything from the parent node '<item>' if its '<attribute16><category>' is Fishing.

Comment: ok, I think I see your problem;  the issue isn't about grabbing the item within the node, it's about the loading of the file correct?  If this is the case, sadly it does not appear to be possible:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7629054/3044080

Comment: if you just want the items from the parent, it is absolutely possible.

Comment: Check this out though:  http://php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php

Comment: Yes exactly, if I load the file, I think I have already slowed down the page for the user. Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: there are apparently other methods that work better than simplexml alone.  You can use a cursor to find the part of the file you need to speed things up.   see this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7629480/3044080

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can SimpleXML load only a partial of a XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628999/can-simplexml-load-only-a-partial-of-a-xml)